# python guess the number - try again after overguessing

Tags: python, random, numbers

I have made a simple Guess the number program, but i don't know how to make the try again after guessing wrong 3 times. Any tips and tricks?

```
from random import randint
for i in range(1): 
random_value = randint (1,10)

print "Guess the number"
tryes = 1
while tryes <= 3:
guess_1 = input('>')

    if guess_1 > random_value:
        print "The number is lower"
        tryes = tryes + 1
    elif guess_1 < random_value:
        print "The number is higher"
        tryes = tryes + 1
    elif guess_1 == random_value:
        print "You guessed right"
        tryes = tryes + 3
    else:
        print "Invalid answer"

print "You won! Lets try that again shall we?"
```

Comment: just add `os.system("python %s"%sys.argv[0])` to the end

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
while True: #this will just make it loop forever ...
    #for i in range(1):  ## No idea what this was meant to do ...
    random_value = randint (1,10)

    print "Guess the number"
    tryes = 1
    while tryes <= 3:
        guess_1 = input('>')

        if guess_1 > random_value:
            print "The number is lower"
            tryes = tryes + 1
        elif guess_1 < random_value:
            print "The number is higher"
            tryes = tryes + 1
        elif guess_1 == random_value:
            print "You guessed right"
            tryes = tryes + 3
        else:
            print "Invalid answer"

    print "You won! Lets try that again shall we?"
```

Comment: So why aren't you casting?

Comment: python2 `input("Enter Int:")` is the same as python3 `eval(input("Enter Int:"))` ... its usually more advisable to use `raw_input` and cast, however that is unrelated to OP's problem

Comment: oops I did have a minor indentation error ... and there are some logic issues with OP's code

Comment: Now it starts over again, but how do i make it continue after guessing right? Now it just starts over even if i guess right.

Comment: You should make this as a function 'def'. Then you can extend your program with more functions. You can also use different classes e.g. main, failed, error, next.